# Strange behaviour when dragging sortable Bootstrap panels with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm getting my teeth into jQuery UI and Bootstrap, and I'm trying to implement draggable/sortable Panels, which is almost working.

I'm using the `container` model (instead of `container-fluid`) and I have multiple panels.  The panels are setup to spread over differing columns depending on the screen size.

Dragging a panel that is **not** in the right-most column moves the panel with the mouse, and the placeholder moves under the mouse **unless** you move it over the right-most column.

If you drag a panel from the right-most column, the panel appears in the location of the **next** panel.

**Can anybody explain why this is happening, and how I make it work as it should - i.e. I should be able to drag any panel and place it in any location?**

To see the issue in action, please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6vnjhsp/) (click [here to see it full size](https://jsfiddle.net/L6vnjhsp/embedded/result/)) and try dragging a panel that **isn't** in the right column over to the right column.  And try dragging a panel that **is** in the right column anywhere.

The HTML is setup as follows (showing just the first two panels)...

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="sortable" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Test 1</div>
            <div class="panel-body">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Test 2</div>
            <div class="panel-body">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is setup as...

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable().disableSelection();
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.2, jQuery UI 1.10.3, Bootstrap 3.3.2

---

The answer provided by @AlexStack (to add a transparent border-top to each `<div>`) is almost there, but doesn't work in *current* FireFox (36.0.1 at time of testing/writing)... the same issue occurs.

Does anybody know a solution that covers all major browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of jQuery UI (or Bootstrap, I'm not sure which one). But adding an invisible border fixes the problem:

```
#sortable > div {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can see the solution in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L6vnjhsp/2/

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's not a problem with my code.  This is a massive step forward, and is working in Chrome/IE... but unfortunately doesn't work with FireFox (testing with 36.0.1)

Comment: Again it's not your problem. I tested it in Firefox 38.0a2 (Firefox Developer edition 2015-03-13) and it works.

Comment: Slightly annoying that it only works in a version of FireFox that is not yet released... especially as that is my personally preferred browser, and I'm not keen on moving to non-current versions

Answer (score 1):

I had many problems of this same type, and also with some extreme flickering, but I was able to make this work perfectly by ditching the `col-md-*` elements and going for a list instead, as the jQuery UI sortable example is on their site. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

```
<style>
    #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
    #sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>    
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I used a simple workaround in css.

Here the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaphp/dvtqmd6g/1/)

```
margin-right:-1px;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing any improvement - still doesn't work in FF38

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
#sortable > div {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure how this is different from the answer submitted a week ago.,, and still doesn't work in FireFox